# i18next check for unused translation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, translation, i18next, react-i18next

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a good way / tool / package to checking for unused translations

I've seen it for rails, like i18n-tasks but nothing for react

I'm currently using react-i18next, but it could be anything that looks through your translation file

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: There are [multiple extraction tools](https://react.i18next.com/guides/extracting-translations#2-using-an-extraction-tool) available. Based on these, you can easily write a small tool that will warn you when it finds an existing translation that is no longer found in the extracted keys (if the tools are not already doing that automatically)

Answer (score 8):

#### List unused translations keys

There is [i18-unused](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-unused) library which prints list of all unused keys for all json files.

```sh
npm install --save-dev i18n-unused
```

To make it work make sure you add config `i18n-unused.config.js` in root directory with path to your locales (localesPath) and all js files (srcPath).

```js
//i18n-unused.config.js
module.exports = {
  localesPath: 'src/locales',
  srcPath: 'src',
};
```

Then run:

```sh
i18n-unused display-unused
```

Comment: I followed your steps but I got this error: "i18n-unused : The term 'i18n-unused' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet" on a windows machine

Comment: @Nemus Check if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. You can also use npx i18n-unused display-unused

Answer (score 3):

I used [i18next-scanner](https://github.com/i18next/i18next-scanner). It can remove unused translations (see removeUnusedKeys options).

Answer (score 1):

if you‘re using i18next combined with locize, there‘s a dedicated i18next plugin to find unused translations: https://docs.locize.com/guides-tips-and-tricks/unused-translations

Answer (score 0):

I use react-18next frequently, and I don't believe there is a tool to check for this. Although, is it necessary? The performance losses are probably negligable.

Comment: Thanks for your response. It’s more so cause I want these keys to be translated into 20 different languages and it would become pretty costly. I’ve been reverse checking it manually but it would be nice to automate / clean up in general