# React i18next - how to find unused translation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, internationalization, translation

I use `react-i18next` in my project.

en.json

```
{
  "translation": {
    "header": {
       "comment": "Comment"
     }
  }
}
```

i18n.ts

```
import en from 'assets/locales/en.json';

const resources = {
  en: { ...en, translation: { ...en.translation } },
};

export const initLanguage = async () => {
  await i18next.use(initReactI18next).init({
    compatibilityJSON: 'v3',
    resources: resources,
    lng: "en",
    fallbackLng: "en",
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false,
    },
  });
};
```

Referencing on [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71295725/10686620),
Now I use [i18n-unused](https://www.npmjs.com/package/i18n-unused) to identify unused translation.

```
module.exports = {
  localesPath: 'assets/locales',
  srcPath: 'src',
};
```

When I run `i18n-unused display-unused`, it shows that lots of translations are unused, but actually most of those translations are being used.

Result

```
Unused translations count: 840
...
'translation.header.documents' 
...
```

In my code

```
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
...
const { t } = useTranslation();
...

return (
  <Header title={t('header.documents')}/>
)
```

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: [issue](https://github.com/mxmvshnvsk/i18n-unused/issues/34)